# I have an error with OutputStream

Tags: java, outputstream, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to unzip a file, called 'resources.zip' and when I do I get this error.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\VAPOUR\Destiny\resources (Access is denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at classes.a.extractFolder(a.java:198)
```

On line 198... It's;

```
OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(output2.toString());
```

If you need more, I can always add some! :) Thanks for the help :)

Comment: The error says `resources` rather than `resources.zip`. What is the exact value of `output2`?

Comment: Its in C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\VAPOUR\Destiny\resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are calling "outputs.mkdirs()" before attempting to write the file, then the problem is that you are creating a directory which is the name of the file you are attempting to write.

in order to create the dir and then the file, do something like:

```
File f = new File("...");

// create all parent dirs for the target file
f.getParentFile().mkdirs();

// ... now write the file itself ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the file you are trying to access exists (File**NotFound**Exception) and also make sure that you have permission to read it. It's also possible that you're not allowed to open a .zip file as a directory (you're trying to access `resources`, not `resources.zip`). Perhaps try to access `resources.zip` directly instead of accessing the directory and then accessing the file?

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

that exception is usually thrown if the directory you're trying to write to does not exist

Comment: outputs.mkdirs(); is before the
OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(outputs.toString());